# Expression instead of statement

Tags: c#

How to easily turn a statement to an expression without too much clutter?
I want to update a variable but then 'return' a different value from inside ?: operator and store it in variable.

This problem can be solved using the C++'s evil comma operator, in JS using an arrow function that is immediatelly called, in F# thanks to all ifs being expressions etc.

Just to make sure it is clear, I will write C++ code that would do what I want:

```
MyStruct obj;
int x = NULL;
x = x ? x : (setObj(obj), obj.x);
```

But that would look very ugly in C# because there is not comma operator and the syntax for creating an anonymous Func with one argument and one line to update the variable and another to retrieve the value would already take up a lot more space and make the code less readable than just using a normal if statement.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3086

Comment: `x = x ?? new Func<MyStruct>(() => { obj = getObj(); return obj; })().x` will do. But I doubt it's worth the trouble

Comment: @haim770 Yeah, exactly, this just looks... too bad.

Answer (score 3):

Updated to answer your updated question and use the ??= operator:

If setObj returns the object then:

```
x ??= setObj(obj).x
```

If setObj returns something other than `void`:

```
x ??= (setObj(obj) is var _ ? obj.x : 0);
```

If setObj returns `void` (as per @haim770 comment):

```
x ??= new Func<MyStruct>(() => { setObj(obj); return obj; })().x;
```

Readability is questionable on the second two.

---

Answer to original question:

How about:

```
MyStruct obj;
int? x = null;
x ??= (obj = getObj()).x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
MyStruct obj;
int? x = null;
x = x ?? (obj = getObj())?.x;
```

I just added ?. in case getObj returns null.
Instead of condensing code, I also suggest you to look into readability and ease of debugging code

Comment: The difference here is that the variable obj is not updated on the important line. But thank you for the rest, that|s not bad.

Comment: I have realised why I could not come up with this solution. I had a slightly different problem in mind. I have updated the question to match the actual problem. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want an inline function? Then you can use:

```
var k = true;            
Func<int, bool> greater = (x) => x > 1;
k = k ? k : greater(1);
```

Comment: That seems like a reasonable point. My reasoning was that this is such a simple thing that there should be a decent, simple and short way of writing it down.